# letter f treated as tab in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA macro that reads in multiple text files into separate sheets in one Excel workbook.  Everything works fine, except that VBA is treating the letter "f" as a tab.  (All files are tab-delimited.)  That is, when it sees the letter "f" in a string, to pushes all downstream text in the string into the next field / cell in Excel.  Has anybody encountered this before?  If so, how did you fix it?

```
Sub MultipleTextFilesIntoExcelSheets()
    Dim i As Integer 'a counter to loop through the files in the folder
    Dim fname As String, FullName As String 'fname is the name of the file, and FullName is the name of its path
    Dim ws As Worksheet 'a workbook object for the workbook where the current macro is running

    i = 0 'seed the counter

    'get the name of the first text file
    fname = Dir("C:\dummy_path\*txt")

    'loop through the text files to put them onto separate sheets in the Excel book
    While (Len(fname) > 0)
        'get the full path of the text file
        FullName = "C:\dummy_path\" & fname
        i = i + 1 'get ready for the next iteration

        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet" & i) 'the current sheet

        With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & FullName, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
            .Name = "a" & i
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 437
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = True    'we are using a tab-delimited file
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileOtherDelimiter = False
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2) 'there are 21 columns of text type in each file
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
        fname = Dir
    Wend
End Sub
```

Here is an example text file I'm reading in:

```
Header1 Header2  
finance stuff
```

I was able to fix my code.  Here is the solution:

```
Sub MultipleTextFilesIntoExcelSheets()
    Dim i As Integer 'a counter to loop through the files in the folder
    Dim fname As String, FullName As String 'fname is the name of the file, and FullName is the name of its path
    Dim ws As Worksheet 'a workbook object for the workbook where the current macro is running

    i = 0 'seed the counter

    'get the name of the first text file
    fname = Dir("C:\dummy_path\*txt")

    'loop through the text files to put them onto separate sheets in the Excel book
    While (Len(fname) > 0)
        'get the full path of the text file
        FullName = "C:\dummy_path\" & fname
        i = i + 1 'get ready for the next iteration

        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet" & i) 'the current sheet

        With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & FullName, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
            .Name = "a" & i
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 65001 'this is critical
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = True    'we are using a tab-delimited file
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            ' .TextFileOtherDelimiter = False 'get rid of this
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2) 'all files have 21 columns, data type = text (2)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
        fname = Dir
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: How are we supposed to reproduce this problem?

Comment: Just tried with Excel 2010 and your example data -> no problem here. Which Excel version?

Comment: I'm also on Excel 2010.  I just tried the example I gave as well.  It worked.  It might be unique to the actual files I'm using.

Comment: Array(1, 1, 1) looks like a potential culprit to me.

Comment: Have you perchance done a text to columns with `f` as the splitting character? If you did, just redo one removing that parameter and see if it addresses the issue.

Comment: No, I haven't done any text-to-column actions.  It's just a straight read from the text files.

Comment: Also, I fixed the Array(1,1,1) problem.  I also tried    .TextFilePlatform = xlWindows  but it didn't resolve anything.

Comment: I fixed my code.  It works, now.  I had to change the     TextFilePlatform value, as well as get rid of the     TextFileOtherDelimiter line.

Comment: "Solved it" and adding the solution in your question isn't how SO works. [Self-answers are fine](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (and are even encouraged), but the proper way to do it is to post the solution as an *answer*, not as content of the question itself.

Comment: Sorry.  SO wouldn't let me solve my own answer at this time, since I have < 10 reputation points.

Comment: You're over that hurdle now so post your solution as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub MultipleTextFilesIntoExcelSheets()
    Dim i As Integer 'a counter to loop through the files in the folder
    Dim fname As String, FullName As String 'fname is the name of the file, and FullName is the name of its path
    Dim ws As Worksheet 'a workbook object for the workbook where the current macro is running

i = 0 'seed the counter

'get the name of the first text file
fname = Dir("C:\dummy_path\*txt")

'loop through the text files to put them onto separate sheets in the Excel book
While (Len(fname) > 0)
    'get the full path of the text file
    FullName = "C:\dummy_path\" & fname
    i = i + 1 'get ready for the next iteration

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet" & i) 'the current sheet

    With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & FullName, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
        .Name = "a" & i
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 65001 'change this value according to the encoding of the text file
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True    'we are using a tab-delimited file
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2) 'all files have 21 columns, data type = text (2)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    fname = Dir
Wend
```

End Sub